# compound tags in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have code below :

```
<tr>
<td><b>Item 1</b></td>
<td>Name 1</td>
<td><i><b>Price 1</b></i></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Item 2</b></td>
<td>Name 2</td>
<td><i><b>Price 2</b></i></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Item 3</b></td>
<td>Name 3</td>
<td><i><b>Price 3</b></i></td>
</tr>
```

How do I get value of Price 1, Price 2, Price 3 in BeautifulSoup's find_all syntax with multiple tag as above (`<td><i><b>`)?. Thanks for any solution.

I tried this :

```html
import os
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baca = open("asal.html", "r").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(baca, "html.parser")
saring = soup.find_all(['td','b'])
for a in saring:
 print a.text
```

Comment: can you give us a sample of your code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CSS selector via `select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method to select element based on ancestors hierarchy i.e select `b` where the parent is `i` and the grandparent is `td` :

```
>>> raw = '''<div>
... <tr>
... <td><b>Item 1</b></td>
... <td>Name 1</td>
... <td><i><b>Price 1</b></i></td>
... </tr>
... <tr>
... <td><b>Item 2</b></td>
... <td>Name 2</td>
... <td><i><b>Price 2</b></i></td>
... </tr>
... <tr>
... <td><b>Item 3</b></td>
... <td>Name 3</td>
... <td><i><b>Price 3</b></i></td>
... </tr>
... </div>'''
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(raw, "lxml")
>>> soup.select("td > i > b")
[<b>Price 1</b>, <b>Price 2</b>, <b>Price 3</b>]
```